# retry with varying intervals on each time

Tags: java, android, algorithm, retry-logic

I am working on a ble-android communication app. I am getting TYPE_GATT_ERROR sometimes when I try to read values from ble device. So I like to retry the scan and reading values each time the TYPE_GATT_ERROR is seen. first time when it happens, I want to start the scan again after 30secs and if that time also if the code reaches TYPE_GATT_ERROR segment, It should start scan again after 1 min and third time if it reaches the error segment, It should rescan with time interval 2mins. How can I do that with the below code segment? The Elseif case with the TYPE_GATT_ERROR condition is where I want to implement the retry algorithm.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver bleServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            String type = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    BleReceivedService.EXTRA_TYPE);
            if (BleReceivedService.TYPE_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(type)){
                Log.d(TAG, " MYTAG DashBoard onReceive TYPE_GATT_CONNECTED");
                if (BleReceivedService.getGatt() != null){
                    BleReceivedService.getGatt().discoverServices();
                    Log.d(TAG, " Connect Device");
                    stopScan();
                }
            } else if (BleReceivedService.TYPE_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(type)){
                Log.d(TAG, " MYTAG Disconnect Device");
                Log.d(TAG, " MYTAG DashBoard onReceive TYPE_GATT_DISCONNECTED");
                BleReceivedService.getInstance().disconnectDevice();
          if(isScanning) {
             Log.d("ScanCheck","Scanning after disconnection");
          stopScan();
          }
            } else if (BleReceivedService.TYPE_GATT_ERROR.equals(type)) {
                Log.d(TAG, " MYTAG DashBoard onReceive TYPE_GATT_ERROR");
//here i want to call startscan() method in the above described fashion
            } else {
                //do someting
            }
        }
    };
```

Please help me with the code to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.